# Access AWS SNS service without using Secret key and access key

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to send SMS using AWS Simple Notification Service from EC2 containers in AWS. Is it possible to send the SMS without using Secret Key and Access Key.

In IAM any permissions can be added ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can assign an IAM role to the instance itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to clarify the previous answer.

It is possible to assign a role to a running EC2 instance with required permissions (e. g. sending a message through SNS)

The client running on the instance doesn't need to provide any explicit AWS credentials (under the hood the SDK implement will acquire  and use temporary credentials from the metadata service)

Comment: @MohitAgrawal, How did you create the AmazonSNS client in this case? I tried with AmazonSNS amazonSNS = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.defaultClient(); but it is not working. It is looping in itself.

Comment: @3AK This option assumes you run the client on AWS (EC2, ECS or Lambda) and you assign a resource role to the container.  You ma check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229544/aws-create-an-amazonsnsclient

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning required action permission from below list to the IAM role attached to EC2 instance

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_sns.html

Comment: upvoted (people are wierd) , if someone doesn't understand the answer or is looking for something else should clarify / comment

Comment: @gusto2 thanks mate. It's not like I hate downvotes, but at least explain the downvote so that I can improve myself. thanks again!